# Flutter AppAuth: Is there a way to hide the url address and the bottom navigation bar when launch url in app?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, appauth

I'm looking into a way to make a better native feel for my flutter project. Is it possible to customize the safari launch view inside the flutter app, in a way I could hide the url, refresh button along with the bottom navigation bar?
This is how it currently looks like, and I want to hide the parts in the red box

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

To get a native web view in flutter, you'd have to use [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) plugin, this allows you to use widgets on top of the webview and hide URL and other things in a browser.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that, but I need the appauth plugin for oauth2 flow. Is it possible to achieve this authentication flow through webview?

Comment: did you manage to find a solution for this @TienThai ?

Comment: unfortunately not, it could be solved by combining webview and url_launcher, but eventually the oauth with pkce wouldn't work since it's not supported